# Task.WhenAll too slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, parallel-processing

I need to call same API 5 times. First way is to call it in a `foreach` loop, which means that the
next one will be called when the previous one is finished and so on..

```
foreach (var moduleName in AllModules.Modules)
{
  ModulesRoles = await WebAssemblyHttpService.Fetch<GetRolesByModuleNameResponse>("nemo", moduleName, HttpMethod.Post, "/api/admin/getmoduleroles"...);
}
```

This takes about 100ms per request resulting in 500ms total wait time. [image: waterfall using foreach]

Second and better way is to make a list of Tasks and wait for them using `Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks)`. Now the requests are sent in parallel which should significantly reduce the wait time, but for some reason they all take about 500ms.

```
await Task.WhenAll(AllModules.Modules.Select(async moduleName =>
{
  ModulesRoles = await WebAssemblyHttpService.Fetch<GetRolesByModuleNameResponse>("nemo", moduleName, HttpMethod.Post, "/api/admin/getmoduleroles"...);
}));
```

[image: waterfall using Task.WhenAll()]

My question is, why is it so slow. Shouldn't I also wait for each request about 100ms, but since they are in parallel the total wait time should be 100ms?

**Edit:** This is a Blazor App

**Edit2:** `.Fetch` implementation

```
var request = ForgeRequest(requestModel, httpMethod, uri, browserRequestMode, browserRequestCredentials);
            return await SendRequest<T>(clientName, request, token);
```

`.ForgeRequest` implementation

```
_spinnerService.Show();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, uri);
            if (httpMethod != HttpMethod.Get)
                request.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestModel), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.SetBrowserRequestMode(browserRequestMode);
            request.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(browserRequestCredentials);

            return request;
```

Comment: Is this a Blazor application?

Comment: Yes. Blazor WebAssembly.

Comment: Why are you overwriting `ModuleRoles` every time? Are you missing code?

Comment: Also, can you please share the code for `WebAssemblyHttpService`? I'm curious if you are using any HTTP clients in a non-static way which may be the cause for this

Comment: I overwrite it every time because some of the code is missing in an example since it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @RandomSlav Please modify the question to include the formatted code as well as the type of `ModuleRoles` at the very least, thanks :)

Comment: @RandomSlav Thank you for the info but please modify the question as it's much easier to read that way

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary `ModuleRoles` is just a list of strings

Comment: @RandomSlav Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - we need the full method at the very list including the return type, arguments etc.

Comment: Seems like there could easily be server-end explanations for this. Even if there's no explicit throttling mechanism, if there's some shared resource that needs to be accessed exclusively by each request, you're not going to speed things up by sending multiple requests in parallel from the client-end.

Comment: Suggest rewrite the web API so you can get all the moduleroles in a single call.